# DataGridView filter data based on Radio Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, radio-button

I have some Radio buttons

One Radio Button is called Open Tickets
Another is called Closed Tickets

When the Open Tickets button is pressed, I want to filter the data presented on the DataGridView

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: Are you using databinding?  Make a new query?

Comment: My datagridview is using bindingsource

Comment: The data is all Text and Numeric fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your `datagridview` by applying a Filter to your `BindingSource`. MSDN has an example of how to filter your binding source. Link is below as well as code.

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx):

```
private void PopulateDataViewAndFilter()
{
    DataSet set1 = new DataSet();

    // Some xml data to populate the DataSet with.
    string musicXml =
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
        "<music>" +
        "<recording><artist>Coldplay</artist><cd>X&amp;Y</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>Dave Matthews</artist><cd>Under the Table and Dreaming</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>Dave Matthews</artist><cd>Live at Red Rocks</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>Natalie Merchant</artist><cd>Tigerlily</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>U2</artist><cd>How to Dismantle an Atomic Bomb</cd></recording>" +
        "</music>";

    // Read the xml.
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(musicXml);
    set1.ReadXml(reader);

    // Get a DataView of the table contained in the dataset.
    DataTableCollection tables = set1.Tables;
    DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);

    // Create a DataGridView control and add it to the form.
    DataGridView datagridview1 = new DataGridView();
    datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    this.Controls.Add(datagridview1);

    // Create a BindingSource and set its DataSource property to
    // the DataView.
    BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
    source1.DataSource = view1;

    // Set the data source for the DataGridView.
    datagridview1.DataSource = source1;

    //The Filter string can include Boolean expressions.
    source1.Filter = "artist = 'Dave Matthews' OR cd = 'Tigerlily'";
}
```

Comment: @CocoaDev basically you will filter your bindingsource based on whether or not you want open/closed records. The one thing I recommend is making sure that you provide your users with a way to clear the filter.

Comment: I don't know if this matters but the columns I want to filter are not being displayed in my DataGridView. (I edited the columns and left many columns out on purpose)

Comment: I think you can filter on columns not showing because you are filtering the bindingsource but you would have to test it